# Runtime Exception: Font not found for every font i've tried - Android

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-assets, custom-font

I have a custom extended `TextView` I am using for custom fonts within my application, but for some reason I keep getting a run-time exception where the program can't find the font in question.

The format of the directory I'm using is `main > assets > fonts > Portrait-Light.ttf`

[image: screenshot of directory]

I've looked everywhere for a solution but they all seem to be rounding to the same answers on SO.

**CustomFontTextView.java :**

```
public class CustomFontTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
        Log.e("it gets here", "custom font");
        Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("Roboto-Italic.ttf", context);
        setTypeface(customFont);
    }
}
```

**FontCache.java**

```
class FontCache {

    private static HashMap<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<>();

    static Typeface getTypeface(String fontname, Context context) {
        Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(fontname);
        if (typeface == null) {
            try {
                typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontname);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("failed", e.getMessage());
            }
            fontCache.put(fontname, typeface);
        }
        return typeface;
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
 <icn.premierandroid.misc.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/switch_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/are_you_over_18_years_old"/>
```

I have tried this with different formats such as `.otf` and with different fonts such as `Roboto-Italic.ttf` and another random one from dafont.com called `Sunset-Clouds.ttf` but still i get the error message, what is going on? this should be working. I've even updated all plugins such as Gradle, Grade-Wrapper distribution and Android gradle plugin just in case.

I have also tried the single way of doing it:

```
    AssetManager am = context. getApplicationContext(). getAssets();
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(
    am, String.format(Locale.US, "fonts/%s", "portrait-light.ttf"));
```

Am i missing something?

Update:

Removal of the catch reveals this stacktrace.

> Process: icn.premierandroid, PID: 3829
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{icn.premierandroid/icn.premierandroid.RegisterActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error
>   inflating class icn.premierandroid.misc.CustomFontTextView
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>   .....
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100:
>   Error inflating class icn.premierandroid.misc.CustomFontTextView
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
>
> .....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
>
> ....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found
>   fonts/GleegooRegular.ttf
>                         at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:272)
>                         at icn.premierandroid.misc.FontCache.getTypeface(FontCache.java:21)
>                         at icn.premierandroid.misc.CustomFontTextView.applyCustomFont(CustomFontTextView.java:28)
>                         at icn.premierandroid.misc.CustomFontTextView.(CustomFontTextView.java:18)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>
> .....

UPDATE 2:

Okay, so there is a weird work-around for this. Apparently android studio doesn't like it when you add the `assets` folder straight into the `main` folder inside `app/src/main`. You need to add it into the `app/src/main/res` folder first and then move it to the `main` folder. Don't have a clue why it's like this but it solved my problem.

Comment: please post error stacktrace

Comment: @maxost, added it for you, bud.

Comment: "Font asset not found fonts/GleegooRegular.ttf", i am unsure but i do not see this font in your fonts directory.

Comment: it was added after, sorry i was debugging it whilst waiting for answers (just trying out a new font)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real problem is that you haven't configured your assets folder. If you had, it would look like this in Project view:

[image: Asset folder with pictogram]

Or like this in Android view:

[image: Asset folder with pictogram, Android view]

So you should simply add this folder as assets folder in Studio:
Click on your project structure window (or press Alt+1), then press Alt + Insert and select Folder/Assets Folder. Then put your fonts there.

Update from OP:

> Okay, so there is a weird work-around for this. Apparently android studio doesn't like it when you add the assets folder straight into the main folder inside app/src/main. You need to add it into the app/src/main/res folder first and then move it to the main folder. Don't have a clue why it's like this but it solved my problem.

Comment: I did add it this way, I'll try and remove it and add it again. i'll let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

We wrote this class for our needs. It allows to set our custom fonts using attribute, like this:

```
app:customFont="Roboto-Medium.ttf"
```

Hope you find it useful:

```
public class TextViewFonted extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextViewFonted";

    public TextViewFonted(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewFonted(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public TextViewFonted(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewFonted);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewFonted_customFont);
        if (customFont == null) customFont = "Roboto-Regular.ttf";
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface", e);
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        setLineSpacing(getTextSize() * 0.3f, 0.75f);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And to be able to use this custom attribute, you should add to your *attrs.xml* next block (so *R.styleable.TextViewFonted_customFont* will work):

```
 <declare-styleable name="TextViewFonted">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
 </declare-styleable>
```

In our case, we put fonts in the root of *assets* folder, but you could change this behavior in method *setCustomFont()*

**Update**

To add this font, for example, we use

[image: Screenshot of fonts that are in assets folder]

```
app:customFont="Comfortaa-Bold.ttf"
```

Comment: i'll give this a try and let you know, thanks for answering.

Comment: unfortunately, it's still giving me " java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found" inside the fonts directory and inside the assets directory.

Comment: Look at the updated answer, I've added a screenshot with assets. Are you sure that you didn't mispell the font name?

Comment: I'm 100% bud, double and triple checked it.

Comment: upvoted for this class too, i used it and will carry on using it. I like the attr feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
put .ttf fonts in app > assets > fonts > Roboto-Italic.ttf
```

And then in onCreate method,

```
Typeface Roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf");
```

and set font in textview,etc

```
textview.setTypeface(Roboto);
```

Comment: ill try it out and let you know.